# Bootstrap vueJS table with v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

So in my project i'm having kind of an issue,

So what i'm trying to do is that i have an a list of users (object) in this object i have a property `teamId`(called from an api endpoint) and i have to short them in a multiple table (bootstrap vue b-table), each of them is a team.
So i'm doing it that i have a function that look at the entire list of users and return the users only in this `teamId` then in my template i'm doing a v-for of boostrap table but the table require `:items="items"` and i can't put the function return inside this `:items="items" exemple: :items="myfunction(teamId)"` so i'm just lost cause i have to create a new `items` array everytime the v-for (with the teamId parameter) is iterating
I'm using b-table cause i need a easy selectable table

Do you guys have any suggestions?
Protject is in vueJS 2

Comment: hey mate, You can create computed property with filtered items and bind items to that..

Comment: But i can't put parameters to computed function no ? As v-for is iterating i'm calling {myComputedFunction(teamId)} ? will it work ?

Comment: if you put some code in your question maybe I can show you the way :)

Comment: Sure give me couple min so i get home

Comment: I posted the function and the v-for

Comment: Did you try just to return `this.teamItems` from function?

Comment: Yes i forgot to put it there cause i changed the function but it doesn't work, my tables are empty

Comment: For me it's because i'm clearling  this.teamItems = [];  at the begining of the function so it only contain the current team value and because of that if the last team is empy all are empty so idk how to do

Comment: Because of the api call you need to wait for response. Maybe you should create new component from your table and just pass props.

Comment: Yeah i was thinking about that too, thanks for the help, i just wanted to know if there was an option to do it in the same vue as i'm still pretty junior ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
            axiosUserTeam(ID) {
            this.teamItems = [];
            axios.get(
                this.$store.state.settings.API_URL + 'api/Scenarios/' + this.$route.params.scenarioid, {
                    withCredentials: true,
                }
            ).then((response) => {
                if(response.status == 200) {
                    this.usersInScenario = response.data.users;
                        console.log(this.teamFullList[TEAM].teamId) //eslint-disable-line 
                        for(let USER in this.usersInScenario) {
                            const current = this.$store.state.users.find(({userId}) => userId == this.usersInScenario[USER].userId)
                            if(this.usersInScenario[USER].teamId == ID) {
                                this.teamItems.push(
                                {userId: current.userId,
                                    Company: current.company,
                                    teamId: this.usersInScenario[USER].teamId,
                                    first_name: current.firstName,
                                    last_name: current.lastName}
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    console.log(this.teamItems); //eslint-disable-line
                }
            })

        },
```

And here is the v-for :

```
<b-card
                        v-for="(TEAM, INDEX) in teamFullList"
                        :title="TEAM.name"
                        :key="TEAM.teamId"
                        header-tag="header" 
                        footer-tag="footer"
                        style="margin-bottom: 10px;"
                        >
                            <template #header>
                            <div class="d-flex">
                                <div class="d-flex align-items-center w-50">
                                    <span style="margin-right: 5px;" class="material-icons">group_add</span>
                                    <b-button v-if="INDEX == 0">Create a team </b-button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="d-flex align-items-center w-50 justify-content-end">
                                    <b-button @click.prevent="delete_team(TEAM.teamId)" style="display: flex; align-items: center;">Delete {{TEAM.name}} <span style="margin-left: 5px;" class="material-icons">delete</span></b-button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            </template>

                            <b-table
                            :items="axiosUserTeam(TEAM.teamId)" 
                            :fields="teamfields"
                            selectable
                            @row-selected="onTeamSelected"
                            select-mode="multi"
                            class="text-md-left"
                            >
                            <template #cell(selected)="{ rowSelected }">
                                <template v-if="rowSelected">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&check;</span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Selected</span>
                                </template>
                                <template v-else>
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Not selected</span>
                                </template>
                            </template></b-table>

                            <template #footer>
                                <em>STATS</em>
                            </template>

                            <div class="d-flex text-md-right">
                                <b-button v-if="userInTeamSelected.length < 1" class="ml-1" size="sm" disabled>Remove users</b-button>
                                <b-button @click="moveSelectedUser('team', null)" v-else class="ml-1" size="sm">Remove users</b-button>
                            </div>
                        </b-card>
```

Comment: Hi, Is this the answer to your question? or it's just your code that has an issue?

Comment: Yeah, i completly changed the way tables was working. So i made a separate component {teamTables} then just v-for the component sending props. And it works perfectly like that, so each component have ther own variables (items) in ther tables